Why are the various node editor views out of sync with each other, and how do I fix it?
I'm using scripting to create node groups. Here's a dummy example that creates two groups, a shader group and a geometry group, both with nothing but a reroute at [0,0].
import bpy
nodeGroupS = bpy.data.node_groups.new("d1","ShaderNodeTree")
nodeGroupS.nodes.new("NodeReroute")
nodeGroupG = bpy.data.node_groups.new("d2","GeometryNodeTree")
nodeGroupG.nodes.new("NodeReroute")
nodeGroupG.is_modifier = True

The problems will be explained later - first I'll list two series of steps that demonstrate it. They're only to illustrate the problem, not do anything "real".
Case A

Open a new file. Go to the shading workspace. Run the script.



Add a geometry node modifier to Default Cube. Set it to d2. Switch to the geometry node editor.



Switch to the shader node editor. Add a group node for d1. Note where the reroute is in comparison to the base. (composite image)


Case B

Open a new file. Go to the shading workspace. Run the script.



Switch to the geometry node editor. Add a geometry node modifier to Default Cube. Set it to d2.



Switch to the shader node editor.



Add a group node for d1. Note where the reroute is in comparison to the base. (composite image)


The problem
The issues here are manyfold. (Some of which I didn't cover in these images but are still very real.)

The position of [0,0] is not only inconsistent between the editors, but inconsistent based on the order of steps taken.
Yet, panning one editor around will also pan the others by the same amount, so actually lining up the [0,0]s is not allowed.
But this only sometimes happens when tabbing in and out of groups. It seems that if you change editors while in a group, the behaviour is different compared to if you leave the group first.

The question
How am I supposed to force some sense into all this? Because I'm using scripts to generate nodes, I need to be very exact about where things are appearing in the window. But if the coordinate systems between them aren't the same, yet are being locked together as if they are, I can't even put a reroute at [0,0] and press numpad dot to recenter the view (because for some reason there's no way to otherwise recenter the view without zooming) without breaking some/all the other views.
As a side node, how do I place a node at a specific position without a script? I can't find a way to even get the current position of a node without a script.

Had a bit of difficulty following that, but the reroute seems to be in the same position relative to the group node. Are you sure you’re not just adding the group node in different spots?

The reroute in the last-of-each-case images is where it appears in the window when looking at the innards of the group node; I overlaid it on the image of the parent node so both could be seen at once. The position of the group node itself doesn't matter and is not relevant to the issue.

But it might be, though: What if the position of the group node defines the origin of the coordinate system for in-group nodes?

Moving the group node around does not appear to change anything, so I don't think that's the case.

Please also use the scripting tag if your question is about scripting.

Is it about scripting though? Scripting only reveals the problem - it is not the cause of it. The same issue of "the view position across node editors is locked together incorrectly" happens whether the script is run or not; I'm just using a script to prove it.
